# Regex word can be optional but only if it matches the characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line, grep

Following pattern: `(v[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})(-[0-9]{1,2})?((-schema)?(-dev)?)((-schema)?(-dev)?)` from http://regexr.com/ is meant to be used in a shell script with `grep` and does match the following strings (working example):

- `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-32 version`
- `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-dev version`
- `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-dev-schema version`
- `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-schema version`
- `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-3-schema version`

and so forth

So I made the words `schema` and `dev` optional. They can be ommitted or used in a arbitrary order. What I don't what is this:

- `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-foo version`
  or `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-asfs version`

to match.

I want the option to be a bit more constrained. At the moment the Regex is still matching the stuff that...well actually matches.

This for example:

`Hello I am a text and this is my v1.123.33`

results in an *empty string* while this:

`Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-bla"

still results in `v.1.12.33`

Is this because of the grouping I made? So at least the fully matching groups will be taken for the returned match-string?

Comment: It doesn't match `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.123.33` and what's your  expected match for `Hello I am a text and this is my v1.12.33-bla` ?

Comment: `echo "v1.12.33-bla" | grep -woE '(v[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})(-[0-9]{1,2})?((-schema)?(-dev)?)((-schema)?(-dev)?)'` should return nothing - that's what I actually want. I tried to add ?: to the first grouping. that works for some cases but fails on actually valid strings like `"v13.21.33-dev"`. I'm slowly getting dizzy.

Comment: When you say that using a pattern with `grep` "results in" a given string that is different from a whole input line, are you supposing that you use the `-o` / `--only-matching` option of GNU `grep`?

Comment: Meh only using `-woE` since I only pipe the version string without much noise I'm unsure with the results to `-o` completely. To be honest Im more playing around since I lack in time to really dive into Regex

Comment: "v1.123.33" does not match because your regex does not accept the three-digit middle segment of the version number.  Is that something it *should* accept?

Comment: Note that the `-w` does not help distinguish between "v1.12.33" and "v1.12.33-asfs".  That is, if the first matches the regex, then so will (the initial part of) the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match *only* the version string, disallow extra trailing tags, yet allow trailing unmatched text, you need a regex language that supports lookahead.  Standard `grep` / `egrep` regexes do not support lookahead.

You have two options:

1. Since you seem to be relying on GNU `grep` anyway, you could use a Perl regex, such as

```
v[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){2}(-[0-9]{1,2})?((-schema(-dev)?)?|(-dev(-schema)?)?)?(?!\S)
```

The negative lookahead at the end allows the match to appear at the end of the line, but also requires that if it does not end the line then the next character following the match must be whitespace (which is not itself included in the match).

2. You could give up on completely isolating the target text via `-o`, and instead allow the pattern to match the trailing context, too:

```
v[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){2}(-[0-9]{1,2})?((-schema(-dev)?)?|(-dev(-schema)?)?)?(\s.*)?$
```

In this case, you could isolate the target text in a second step, by stripping off any tail beginning with whitespace.

Note that neither of these pays attention to text *preceeding* the match.  You have similar options for handling that portion as you do for handling the trailing portion.

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expressions are open-ended, you need to specify with `$` where you want the match to end, so you don't let the regex engine silently ignore trailing junk.

With only two tags in the optional set, I would just enumerate the 4 possibilities:

```
(v[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})(-[0-9]{1,2})?(-schema|-dev|-dev-schema|-schema-dev)?$
```

Comment: But this also matches "v1.12.33-dev-dev" and "v1.12.33-schema-schema", which the OP seems to be trying to avoid.

Comment: Regular expressions don't really have a concept of memory; for something this short, then, I'd just enumerate the 4 possiblities and make it optional: `...(-dev|-schema|-dev-schema|-schema-dev)?$`.

Comment: Should be `...(-dev-schema|-dev|-schema-dev|-schema)?`

Comment: Or shorter but less readable `(-dev(-schema)?|-schema(-dev)?)?$`.

Comment: @sln The order doesn't matter.

Comment: Why doesn't the order matter?  `(-A|-AB)` _-AB_ will never get matched.

Comment: I have a `$` at the end of the regular expression; if it matched `-A`, the `B` would be a trailing string that prevents any match.

Comment: There is no context here where the crutch _EOS `$`_ can be used. Do you seen one ?

Comment: "[It] is meant to be used in a shell script with grep". If you object to it precluding matching any trailing words, then replace it with whatever word separator is necessary.

Comment: Only if you actually care about which one matches, and `grep` is matching non-greedily

Comment: Although it is intended to be used with `grep`, and therefore to parse lines one at a time, anchoring to the end of line does not work for the OP's several initial examples, which all have trailing text.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be all the optional expressions lurking at the
edge (end).

You can solve that a few ways, but none are %100 because you'd need
*more* rules to control what matches.
It's not like you can say no `-` is allowed afterword, the engine will
backtrack to one of the range digits `{1,2}` to make a match.

What seems to work for now is passing on a whitespace end edge
or matching the *dev/schema* items.

`(v[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})(-[0-9]{1,2})?(?:(?!\S)|(-(schema|dev)(?:-(schema|dev))?))`

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      v [0-9]{1,2} 
      \. [0-9]{1,2} 
      \. [0-9]{1,2} 
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( - [0-9]{1,2} )?             # (2)
 (?:
      (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary
   |                              # or, 
      (                             # (3 start)
           -
           ( schema | dev )              # (4)
           (?:
                -
                ( schema | dev )              # (5)
           )?
      )                             # (3 end)
 )
```

---

***edit***

If you want to avoid matching the same *schema|dev* word twice, just add
a negative assertion of group 4, before capture group 5 above.

`(v[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})(-[0-9]{1,2})?(?:(?!\S)|(-(schema|dev)(?:-(?!\4)(schema|dev))?))`

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      v [0-9]{1,2} 
      \. [0-9]{1,2} 
      \. [0-9]{1,2} 
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( - [0-9]{1,2} )?             # (2)
 (?:
      (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary
   |                              # or,
      (                             # (3 start)
           -
           ( schema | dev )              # (4)
           (?:
                -
                (?! \4 )                      # Not same word twice
                ( schema | dev )              # (5)
           )?
      )                             # (3 end)
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```sh
grep --perl-regexp \
  '\bv(?:\d{1,2}\.){2}\d{1,2}(?:\-\d{1,2})?(?:\-(?:schema|dev))?(?:\s|$)' \
  path/to/file
```

Where

- the first `\b` is a word boundary(you might want to make it stricter);
- `(?: ... )` expressions are [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap);
- `\s|$` is either a space character, or the end of line

The rest is just refactored for simplicity.

The expression allows only `schema`, or `dev` at the "end".